# Changing colour of accordion panel based on user's input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, accordion

I have an accordion widget working to flip questions, see in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickObrian/b3A7a/14/).

I would like accordion to change colour if user selects specific radio button. There are four choices the user can provide as an answer: Yes (Y), No (N), Not Seen (NS) and Not Applicable (NA).
Specifically, if user selects Y, NS or NA - colour goes "Green"; if N - colour goes "red". If not selected (default state) - nothing changes.

Here is the HTML code of the accordion content.

```
<div id="Q412">
  <table class="QTable">
  <tr>
  <td width="45"  align="left" valign="top" scope="row"><div class="QNumber">4.12</div></td>
  <td width="100%"  align="left" valign="top">
  <div class="QText">Text of the question</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table class="RTable">
  <tr>
  <td width="100%"  align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:20px">
   <div class="Guidance"><p>Content of the guidance</p>
   </div>
   </td>

    <td width="550" align="left" valign="baseline">
    <div class="Response">
      <label><input type="radio" name="Radio412" value="Y" id="Radio_412Y" onchange='radioChange(this, "412")'>Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="Radio412" value="N" id="Radio_412N" onChange='radioChange(this, "412")'>No</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="Radio412" value="NS" id="Radio_412NS" onChange='radioChange(this, "412")'>Not Seen</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="Radio412" value="NA" id="Radio_412NA" onChange='radioChange(this, "412")'>Not Applicable</label>
     </div>

     <div id="responseDetails">
     <div class="Observation">
        <label for="observation">Observation:</label>
        <textarea name="observation" id="Obs412" rows="6" disabled style="width: 530px;" placeholder="Enter text of observation here ..."></textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="DueDate">
            <label for="DueDate">Due date:<br></label>
            <input name="DueDate" class="DueDate" type="date" id="DueDate412"/>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <label for="actions">Actions required to correct and/or prevent this observation:</label>
            <textarea name="actions" id="pa412" rows="6" style="width: 530px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

The accordion widget css file contains the following line which defines default accordion panel colour:

```
.ui-state-default,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background: #e6e6e6; font-weight:normal;color:#555}
```

I know it has got to be a relatively simple JS code to active this functionality but ...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to easily add classes to elements.

Get the radius elements and add a change event. Aprox:

```
 $('input[type=radio][name=NameOfRadioInput]').change(function(){
 if (this.value == 'BLAH') {
        $(#YourAccordionElement).addClass("className1").
    }
    else if (this.value == 'BLEH') {
        $(#YourAccordionElement).addClass("className2").
    }

  }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for a prompt reply. Funnily enough, I had this idea before, the problem is - I do not know how to apply it correctly due to my "beginner's" level of JS knowledge. I have transformed your suggestions into `$('input[type=radio][name=Radio401]').change(function(){
 if (this.value == 'Y') {
        $(.questions).addClass("className1");
    }
    else if (this.value == 'N') {
        $(.questions).addClass("className2");
    }

  }` for question 401, however, I am not sure how to apply class. More to the point, I've got like 400 questions, each with its own id (Radio+id) ...

Comment: Or can we make one example with question 401, just for me to understand the whole thing please

Answer (score 2):

Add classes to your .css file like

```
.classGreen { 
color: green 
} 

.classRed { 
color: red 
}
```

and then refix the js code:

```
if (this.value == 'Y') {
        $(.questions).addClass("classGreen");
}
else if (this.value == 'N') {
        $(.questions).addClass("classRed");
}
```

Then you have to remove the style class added, when you want to remove those green/red colors, with removeClass("classGreen")/ etc... Or use toggleClass("classGreen") instead of addClass/removeClass

Comment: Ok, that is clear. However, the accordion panel background colour is controlled by this line `.ui-state-default,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background: #e6e6e6; font-weight:normal;color:#555}`. If I add class classGreen" how will it interact with existing css for the widget?

Comment: There is no problem, there is a hierarchy in css classes, the color is overriden without "estructural" problems

Comment: Yes, but if I just place additional class under the ui.widget-header etc and include it into JS - it does not work.

Comment: forget ui.widget-header, include these new classes in your own css file

Comment: That's what I did. How classGreen IS APPLIED to accordion header - that is what I do not understand. I mean JS above only says to ADD THIS CLASS - but where to?

Comment: In other words, element .ui-widget-header SPECIFICALLY formats accordion panel, so {whatever} you do to it - changes it. What will classGREEN alter???????

Comment: create a simple html & js code with some divs with a class and then add a new class to them with addClass, same thing

Comment: I missing something trifle, WHAT? ))) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickObrian/a2rgP/)